# How to apply font on characters before ":" regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have a store filled with thousands of specs for each product shown like this:

- Power: 1000W
- Engine Displacement: 100cc
- Start Type: Recoil
- Warranty: 1 Year

I've been trying to figure out if I can apply CSS to just the text before and including the ":" character.
Can you tell me if this is possible with CSS/JS and how I might be able to implement it.

Comment: can you post your sample code?

Comment: The easiest method would be to put the text before `:` inside a separate tag, give it a class and add the styles. Not that it can't be done with JS but its easier to change the markup.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is modify HTML file.

HTML:

```
<span class="class-name">Power:</span> 1000W Engine Displacement
```

In CSS:

```css
.class-name { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: While this works, I'd recommend anybody using this to change `class-name` to something more descriptive.

Comment: Do you know of anyway I can do this without editing the html...I have about 1000 or so products

Comment: If you're going to add some markup, why not make it meaningful? Use a definition list or a heading.

Comment: I don't recommend other such as js because you have about 1000+ products, it will slow down your web application performance. And I believe the framework that you used, generate these product's description passing variable to a HTML markup(Correct me if I'm wrong). eg. Power: {{ product.power }}